# Not able to login to Fabric.io via Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, crashlytics, android-maven-plugin, crashlytics-android

I am not able to login to Fabric site from within the Android Studio.(3.0). - It says Unable to conenct to the internet.
 Though I can login via google chrome. 
 I have all ready put the correct proxy settings in the Android Studio as I can test it via test connection for various sites including fabric.io and maven.

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. It may be best to email support(at)fabric(dot)io on this one, but we'd want to see what's in the logs at this location. On Linux / Windows - idea.log:~/. AndroidStudio/system/logOn Mac - idea.log:~/Library/Logs/AndroidStudio

Comment: Thanks Mike, i am already in touch with you :) ! see you there !